# mod_rewrite issue with specific domain

Tags: magento-1.9, module, url-rewrite

My application base url is `http://216.70.114.XX/~mapple/`

From magento panel i've set `yes to web server rewrites` and my `mod_rewrite` module is enabled.

But unfortunately my url's are not working (getting 404 error) without index.php suffix after base url

Any guess what might be the issue is ?

Comment: What web-server are you using?

Comment: Apache2 with FastCGI.

Comment: `AllowOverride None` in the VirtualHost perhaps?